# Преобразования типов C#

Tags: c#, ооп, классы, наследование, преобразование-типов

Недавно начала изучать C#, и возник вопрос по преобразованию типов.
Есть два класса

```
class Person
{
    public string? Name { get; set; } 

    public Person(string? name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public void PrintMessage()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Name - {Name}");
    }

}
```

и

```
class Employee:Person
{
    public string? Company { get; set; }
    public Employee(string? name, string? company)
    :base(name)
    {
        Company = company;
    }

}
```

И можно сделать такое преобразование

```
Employee Emp_1 = new Employee("Sam", "Google");
Person Per_1 = Emp_1;
Employee Emp_2 = (Employee)Per_1;
```

Но если пытаться сделать так

```
Person person = new Person("Bob");
Employee employee = (Employee) person;
```

То вылетит ошибка.
И вот вопрос, почему так происходит. Ведь по сути, и там и там мы преобразовываем объект класса Person, в объект класса Employee

Comment: `по сути, и там и там мы преобразовываем объект класса Person, в объект класса Employee` нет. Ссылочная переменная - это просто коробочка. Тип ссылочной переменной написан на коробке. А вот реальный тип объекта в коробке - это то, как он был создан. У вас в первом случае Employee, а во втором Person.

Comment: Потому что, очевидно, экземпляр класса Person не является экземпляром класса Employee. Никаких преобразований ни в каком случае не происходит, это просто подмена типа переменной, и нельзя подменить тип на такой, который не соответствует реальному типу объекта

Comment: чтобы понять логику, вот тут `Employee:Person` вы говорите, что любой Employee - это Person. Но вы же не можете сказать обратно, что любой Person - это Employee? Не можете. Это как сказать, что любая утка - это птица, но ведь не любая птица - это утка.

Comment: вот тут `Employee Emp_2 = (Employee)Per_1;` вы берете коробочку на надписью "Person", открываете, достаете оттуда Employee и помещаете в коробочку с надписью "Employee" - тут никаких противоречий.

Comment: а вот тут `Employee employee = (Employee) person;` вы из коробочки с надписью "Person" достаете объект Person, и пытаетесь его поместить в коробочку с надписью Employee - но не получается, ведь Person не является Employee как птица с улицы не обязана быть уткой.